# Viewing all children classes with Yelp

Tags: mallard

I'm viewing the Rhythmbox documentation using Yelp. It's useful, but a few things are missing. Sometimes I want to view all subclasses of a particular class. There doesn't seem to be a way to find that out using the Yelp documentation viewer.

Eg. `RB.Source` has children `RB.AutoPlaylistSource, RB.BrowserSource, RB.MediaPlayerSource, RB.PlaylistSource`.

Is there a way to view such information?

Backstory: I'm viewing documentation generated using g-ir-doc-tool.

Answer (score -1):

It's not so much an issue with Yelp. Yelp just shows the pages that were generated with g-ir-doc-tool, which unfortunately do not include known subclasses at this time. g-ir-doc-tool is still very much a work in progress. You should file an enhancement request at bugzilla.gnome.org, product glib, component introspection.

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=glib&component=introspection